Requested version is not supported ( chrome driver)
[6244:1880:0929/171549.191:ERROR:gl_display.cc(497)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglCreateContext: Requested version is not supported
[6244:1880:0929/171549.225:ERROR:gl_display.cc(497)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglCreateContext: Requested version is not supported
[5568:10620:0929/171550.355:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1063)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for accounts.google.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

I keep getting this error while using wire, but without wire it works fine. Could you guys help me?
I keep getting this error while using wire, but without wire it works fine. Could you guys help me?

the problem here is SSL certificate verification,
so maybe you need to use
in case you are using java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
